# mount ecryptfs add boot time via init.d script

Tags: ecryptfs

I have a directory .cipher which is a mount point to an external storage. 
Now I want to mount this directory to a directory plain at boot time. A running service must access the data without a user logon. I did the following steps:

```
ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
Passphrase: <pass>
Inserted auth tok with sig [<key1>] into the user session keyring
Inserted auth tok with sig [<key2>] into the user session keyring
```

/etc/fstab looks like:

```
 /cipher /plain ecryptfs noauto,user,rw,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=<key2>,ecryptfs_sig=<key1>,ecryptfs_key_bytes=24 0 0
```

If I execute in my /etc/init.d/myService or via console

```
mount -i /plain
```

I get the following lines in the syslog:

```
Oct 25 22:10:16 host kernel: [82852.145162] Could not find key with description: [<key1>]
Oct 25 22:10:16 host kernel: [82852.148914] process_request_key_err: No key
Oct 25 22:10:16 host kernel: [82852.148917] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [<key1>]
Oct 25 22:10:16 host kernel: [82852.156442] One or more global auth toks could not properly register; rc = [-2]
Oct 25 22:10:16 host kernel: [82852.156446] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

How can I mount the ecryptfs at boot time?

Answer (score -1):

:), what is the point in disk encryption that requires no authentication?

what you could do (I've set this up before...), is use a security card eg yubikey4 alongside luks (it supports up to 5 security key slots, so one can have a security key, another can have a password).

The passwords are used to unlock the shared key, which in turn is used to encrypt / decrypt data...

I've not set this up on ecryptfs (only luks) but i think i remember seeing an article.

If I've misunderstood your question I apologize...

Comment: The point is that the encrypted data is on a cloud drive like Amazon S3, Dropbox, ... Everyone on my server can read the data but not the service provider.

Comment: essentially once it's mounted, it's not encrypted, anyone with access to the machine has access to the data. ecryptfs is only encrypted at rest (good if you loose your laptop). Plus if you store the password on the machine there is no point. service provider can mount.